# Ember Data: Pushing the data to the store will not replace the changedAttributes of the record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-model

I am using Ember Data and I have a model say `my-model`. I am having a realtime notification server to update my application if there is any change for a record. When I am editing an attribute of `my-model` from UI, the model has some `changedAttributes` and when the real time notification comes, I am fetching the record from the server and pushing it to the store using `store.push(store.normalize('my-model', data))`.

Now, In the store the model still has my changedAttributes and it is not replaced. So I believe, the Ember Store will not replace the entire record and will replace only the clean attributes of the record when I do a `store.push`. I just want to confirm the behaviour. Can someone confirm if my understanding about this is right?

Answer (score 1):

For something like this I think your best bet is to add a test to ember data itself to cover the desired behavior. This would be much more reliable than anything you might hear on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small Ember Twiddle to test that behavior: https://ember-twiddle.com/a8eb87a1c7e5019214320d81af05aca5?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C As it shows ember-data does not reset dirty attributes if the record is pushed again into the store - at least not for the tested version 3.4.2, which is a little bit outdated.

I wasn't able to find any tests in [ember-data repository](https://github.com/emberjs/data) that covers your use case but I'm also not that familiar with Ember Data's source code. So you might want to open an issue there or ask on [Ember Community Discord](https://discordapp.com/invite/zT3asNS) or [Ember Discussion Forum](https://discuss.emberjs.com/) if this is expected behavior.

To be honest I guess there should be a straight-forward solution to your problem as realtime notification (e.g. through WebSocket) is a common use case.